# Create apt-get install for own software

Tags: software-installation, ppa, repository

I have developed a Java program which I want to create an apt-get repository for it. So every user who wants to install my application can install it by typing "apt-get install myappname".

How can I build it?

Answer (score 14):

You can do this by uploading your program to launchpad and creating PPA.

PPA:

> A PPA is a Personal Package Archive, and is a method of distributing
>   software to users, without requiring developers to undergo the full
>   process of distribution in the main ubuntu repositories.
>
> PPAs can be used to extend the available software in ubuntu to both
>   programs that are not otherwise available in ubuntu, as well as to
>   allow newer versions, such as beta programs, that have not yet
>   undergone sufficient testing to be imported into the main archive.

Quoted from [Ubuntu website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA)

There is a
[Launchpad PPA help file](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA)

To install your program, users will need to add the ppa to their repositories like so:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yourppaname
```

and then after syncing the package index with `apt-get update` they will be able to install it with `apt-get install`

Comment: I developed application with java.it's running under apache tomcat.Should i upload my aplication source code or just apache-tomcat with .war (web archive) file of application ?

Comment: @Pirates you will need to build .deb file. Follow the Launchpad PPA help file link from my answer. If this is some kind of web-application you might want to check the [juju charms](http://juju.ubuntu.com/) as well

Comment: @Symin How is Juju related to building apt packages for a Java app?  On the Juju website I read: _"Model, build and scale your environments on any cloud"_ — this seems more like something related to AWS or Google AppEngine